# daterangepicker callback isn't work at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, jquery-callback, daterangepicker

I have big trouble to run the callback function of my daterangepicker (from http://tamble.github.io/jquery-ui-daterangepicker/)

I didn't see any alert.

I have an 'apply' button at the bottom of the  daterangepicker  UI. I press apply and then fisld host date i've selected but no alert as it should show.

This is the code I've done (really simple code):

```
// will host dates in callback
                var startDate;
                var endDate;
                $('#daterangepicker').daterangepicker(
                  {
                      format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
                      startDate: '2013-01-01',
                      endDate: '2013-12-31'
                  },
                  function (start, end) {
                      alert("hey");
                  }
                );
```

Thanks in advance to help me

**EDIT:**

```
// will host dates
                var startDate;
                var endDate;
                // Show multidatetime picker
                // more infos here: http://tamble.github.io/jquery-ui-daterangepicker/
                $('#daterangepicker').daterangepicker(
                  {
                      onChange: function (start, end) { alert('change : ' + start + ' - ' + end) },
                      format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
                      startDate: '2013-01-01',
                      endDate: '2013-12-31'
                  }
                );
```

This is what I've tested but startDate and endDate are undefined.

**EDIT 2 :**
This is my final code 100%working with the help of EricMathieu

```
// Show multidatetime picker
                // more infos here: http://tamble.github.io/jquery-ui-daterangepicker/
                $('#daterangepicker').daterangepicker(
                  {
                      format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
                      startDate: '2013-01-01',
                      endDate: '2013-12-31'
                  });
...
var tempValues = JSON.parse($('#daterangepicker').val());
alert(tempValues.start);
alert(tempValues.end);
```

Comment: If I look at the documentation the callback uses a different notation than you're using, use `onClose: function() { log('close') }` as mentioned in the documentaiton

Comment: @EricMathieu thanks Eric, but I still have trouble to use the dates, undefined both. How can i do? Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you use the `onChange` callback, you'll have to read the values stored in the `#daterangepicker`, your `start` and `end` variables don't automatically get populated.

A simple approach to get the start / end values would be parse the start and end values (from JSON) in your `onChange` function:

```
var startDate;
var endDate;
// Show multidatetime picker
// more infos here: http://tamble.github.io/jquery-ui-daterangepicker/
$('#daterangepicker').daterangepicker(
    {
        onChange: function () {
            var tempValues = JSON.parse($('#daterangepicker').val());
            alert('change : ' + tempValues.start + ' - ' + tempValues.end)
        },
        format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
        startDate: '2013-01-01',
        endDate: '2013-12-31'
     }
);
```

Comment: if I use the json parsing, no need to use callback. I'll validtae your asking and put my solution as second edit of my question. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You have to call this way:

```
function(start, end, label) {

 console.log(start.toLocaleString() + end.toLocaleString() + label);
}
```

So whole example would look like:

```
$('#date_range').daterangepicker({
        timePicker: false, timePickerIncrement: 30,
        //format: 'DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss',
        format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
        timePicker12Hour: false, 
        opens: 'left',
        locale: { cancelLabel: 'Clear' },
        separator: ' to '}, 
        function(start, end, label) {
console.log(start.toLocaleString() + end.toLocaleString() + label);
}
 });
```